# Convert set of numbers to date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string that has this format

```
20150622
yyyyMMDD
```

But I need to convert this to the following format

```
year-month-date
2015-06-22
```

Is there a way in C# to do what I need? I don't see anyway to treat strings as arrays in C# so what is there?

Comment: As `2015-06-22`? Can you please show an example output?

Comment: Why are you not using the `DateTime` class?  I think you might have an XY problem.  Can we see where this string is coming from?

Comment: Just inserting `-`? 3 x `str.substring(start, len)` calls? Really cant see a reason to dip into DateTime

Answer (score 6):

> I don't see anyway to treat strings as arrays in C#

Strings *are* arrays in .NET. They are arrays of chars, but that doesnt help you!

What you're trying to do is *parse* a string to make a date. And this is done with `DateTime.Parse` and its many overloads/variants

The most obvious way is to use `ParseExact` (or, probably more appropriately `TryParseExact`):

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20150622","yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

To fully answer your question you could then re-generate a string by formatting the `DateTime` with the required format.

---

Another thing to consider is that if you're never interested in the date per se, then you could accomplish your task just using a bit of string mashing.

What you want is `{chars0-3}{hyphen}{chars4-5}{hyphen}{chars6-7}` and this is easy enough

```
var input = "20150622";
var output = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                     input.Substring(0,4),
                     input.Substring(4,2),
                     input.Substring(6,2))
```

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact`, Nice! Didn't know about this gem :)

Answer (score 6):

You can parse your string to `DateTime` with `yyyyMMdd` format (there is no `DD` specifier) and generate it's string representation with `yyyy-MM-dd` format like;

```
string s = "20150622";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output;

```
2015-06-22
```

But if your string parts doesn't range in year, month and day of the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), this solution won't work. In such a case, you can use [`String.Substring` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get parts of your string and format them with `-` delimiter like;

```
var s = "20150622";
var result = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                            s.Substring(0,4),
                            s.Substring(4,2),
                            s.Substring(6,2));
```

result;

```
2015-06-22
```